# GRASS: shift point locations in a random direction

Tags: grass-gis, vector

I have a vector map that contains 100 points.  For each point, I would like to shift it 250 units in a random location.  It's easy enough to shift all points in a specified direction using

```
v.edit map=<mapname> type=point move=250,250
```

But what I need to do is to do this for each point and vary the direction randomly.  The magnitude of the shift can be constant.  (i.e. xshift can be -250 or 250).

Is there a solution that doesn't require me to iterate over the set of points individually?

Ideally, I'd like a solution that doesn't require me to use Python -- I'm trying to do all this with bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [v.perturb](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.perturb.html) - random location perturbations of GRASS vector points. It allows you to select the distribution of perturbation and the deviation in map units.

Comment: Yes.  This is what I need.